# PHP and SOAP data loss when sending to client

Tags: php, xml, soap, data-loss

I have an array of data that I want to send to a SOAP client. 
It all works, but one piece of data isn't transmitted, as revealed by __getLastRequest().

Here's my code

```
<?php

  $test_array = array(
    "request"   =>  array(
      "dateTime"          =>  "2011-12-05T11:37:06.0000000+00:00",
      "brandId"           =>  2,
      "extSysId"          =>  11,
      "extSysPassword"    =>  "xxxxx",
      "customer"          =>  array(
        "title" => "Mr",
        "firstName" =>  "Dec",
        "lastName" => "Test-Two",
        "address" => array(
          "type" => "Residential",
          "pafValidated" => TRUE,
          "houseNumber" => "xx",
          "houseName" => "",
          "line1" => "xx xx",
          "line2" => "",
          "line3" => "xx",
          "line4" => "",
          "line5" => "",
          "postcode" => "xxx xxx"
        ),
        "phones" => array(
          0 => array(
            "type" => "Home",
            "_" => "xxx xxxxxx"
          ),
          1 => array(
            "type" => "Work",
            "preferred" => TRUE,
            "_" => ""
          ),
          2 => array(
            "type" => "Mobile",
            "preferred" => TRUE,
            "_" => ""
          )
        ),
        "email" => "xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com"
      ),
      "nextPurchase"  => array(
        "date" => "2014-05-01"
      ),
      "dataProtection" => array(
        "group" => FALSE,
        "thirdParty" => FALSE
      ),
      "futureContactChannels" => array(
        0 => array(
          "type" => "Whitemail",
          "option" => FALSE
        ),
        1 => array(
          "type" => "Email",
          "option" => FALSE
        ),
        2 => array(
          "type" => "Phone",
          "option" => FALSE
        ),
        3 => array(
          "type" => "SMS",
          "option" => FALSE
        )
      ),
      "vehicleRequests" => array(
        0 => array(
          "derivativeCode" => "xxxxx",
          "type" => "T"
        )
      ),
      "Retailer" => array(
        0 => array (
          "dealerCode" => "00082"
        )
      ),
      "company" => array(
        "companyName" => "",
        "jobTitle" => ""
      ),
      "campaign" => array(
        "code" => "xxxxxxxxx",
        "source" => 69
      ),
      "notes" => "blah balh: ."
    )
  );

$client = new SoapClient("/xxx/xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx.wsdl", array(
  "login" => "xxx", 
  "password" => "xxx",
  "location" => "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxxxx/Some.asmx",
  "uri" => "urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes",
  'trace' => 1,
  'exceptions' => 1,
  'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',
  'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
  'features' => 'SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE'
));


$client->CallComeFunction($test_array);

echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";

echo "*************************************************\n";

echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
```

The Retailed[0]['dealerCode'] is the only piece of info that is omitted from the sent XML.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Ideas? Right now just one... what about formatting your code in a legible way? ;) Seriously: a question that doesn't show much care in how it has been formatted is less likely to get answers/upvotes than one in which the OP showed he/she cared! :)

Comment: If you buy me a larger screen, I will be able to read your code ;).

Answer (score 2):

As mac says, formatting the code would be nice, but one thing I notice is the 'Retailer' field is the only one that's capitalized.  Not sure if the WSDL has any influence on what is sent by the client but it might.

Double check the WSDL and see if the field should be 'retailer' instead.  Any chance you can share the WSDL, btw?

EDIT
After reviewing the WSDL, 'retailer' is the way to go:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="retailer" type="tns:Retailer"/>
```

The payload should be formatted differently as well, it should be

```
"retailer" => array(
    "dealerCode" => "00082"
)
```

per the WSDL

```
<s:complexType name="Retailer">      
    <s:attribute name="dealerCode" type="s:string"/>        
</s:complexType>
```

Comment: The php soap client does indeed ignore data, for which no field is defined in the WSDL. This answer should guide the way!

Comment: @quickshiftin, changing Ratailer to 'retailer' caused an error: "dealerCode not found". Here's the link to the WSDL [link](http://www.autorotation.org/tmp/test.wsdl)
Thanks for the help and sorry about the formatting cock-up